# Can we execute a python script using Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am new to GCP...
Can we execute a python script using some workflow in Cloud Data Fusion?

please tell about which workflow can be used?

Comment: Data Fusion is a `Cloud Data Fusion is a fully managed, cloud-native, enterprise data integration service for quickly building and managing data pipelines`, as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/concepts/overview). Can you tell me what you want to accomplish ? So I can properly address it.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute python scripts by using the Python transform batch plugin in Data Fusion. This plugin can be deployed through the Hub. The Python transform source code can be found [here](https://github.com/data-integrations/python-plugins).

Comment: Could you also tell the diff between Cloud Data Fusion and Dataflow... When to use when?
Advantages and disadvantages of each ... 

I did some pricing .. seems Cloud Data Fusion with same number of instances is coming out to be expensive ... more than double.

Answer (score 0):

nope does not work there is some problem with the python plugin do not use it. the same pipeline with java script plugin was successful while python failed the code was pretty simple to like record['body_0'] += 10

Answer (score 0):

in Python, you must use record['body_0'] = record['body_0'] + 10